# $f,g$ entire functions , $g$ never vanishes , $f$ is not identically $0$ and $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}f(z)/g(z)$ exists , then $f$ never vanishes?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f,g:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be entire functions such that $g(z)\ne 0,\forall z \in \mathbb C$ , and $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ exists ; then is it true that either $f(z)=0 , \forall z \in \mathbb C$ or $f(z)\ne 0, \forall z \in \mathbb C$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$g\neq 0$, then $f/g$ is also entire. $lim_{\mid x\mid\rightarrow \infty}f/g$ exists (I suppose is different of $\infty$), implies that $f/g$ is bounded. A non constant entire function cannot be bounded thus $f/g$ is a constant. This implies that $f=cg$, $c\in C$ a constant.